# Can't send an email with Scrapy(1.5.1) in Python

Tags: python, email, scrapy

I am new to Python and Scrapy.

All I want to achieve, is send a simple email, using only Scrapy.
I have read the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/email.html) from the creators' webpage and I must be missing something, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Here is the code:

```
from scrapy import mail

mailer = mail.MailSender(smtphost='smtp-mail.outlook.com',
                         mailfrom='someone@hotmail.com',
                         smtpuser='someone@hotmail.com',
                         smtppass='mypassword',
                         smtpport=587,
                         smtptls=True,
                         )


def send_mail(mail_sender):
return mail_sender.send(to=["receiver@hotmail.com"],
                        subject="Hello",
                        body="Hello receiver",
                        mimetype='text/plain')


send_mail(mailer)
```

Update: I am running this script with pycharm instead of using `scrapy.cmdline`. Does this have anything to do as to why my code is not working?

This is the output I get:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this must be a rather dull contributor of StackOVerflow. This is a legit question; not everyone finds everything "obvious". There are people new to languages and or frameworks. I'm not deleting this question.. It could actually help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was running the script directly from my IDE *(Pycharm)*.

To run a spider from the IDE, without using a terminal, one could invoke a command programmatically.

Scrapy has a module that allows doing this:

```
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl <spider_name>".split())
```

Scrapy email library works like a charm!